# Interpretation of trend in two models

Tags: time-series, deterministic, trend, stochastic, interpretation

I have estimated the following two models:

```
Δy_t=0.015−0.410Δy_{t−1}−0.220Δy_{t−2}
```

and

```
Δyt=0.400+0.00145t−0.150y_{t−1}−0.325Δy_{t−1}−0.220Δy_{t−2}
```

(Note that yt is the log of monthly trading volume.)

How can I interpret how each is modelling the trend?

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: It's both programming and theoretical I guess. I have run code that produced those models and now I want to know how to interpret the trends and then how to code a way to de-trend each.